# How can I insert data inside parentheses? Dart

Tags: dart

There are inputs:

```
String SQL = "INSERT INTO table () VALUES ()";
List data1 = ['user_id', 'user_name'];
List data2 = ['1', 'test']
```

How can I get "INSERT INTO table (user_id, user_name) VALUES (1, test)"? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with String interpolation `${}`

```
void main() {
  List data1 = ['user_id', 'user_name'];
  List data2 = ['1', 'test'];
  String SQL = "INSERT INTO table (${data1[0]}, ${data1[1]}) VALUES (${data2[0]}, ${data2[1]})";
  
  print(SQL);
}
```

DartPad sample: https://dartpad.dev/?id=39a56cbf2b5cab254902ac7aa3a4324f